# Throw away standard output and error

Tags: bash, pipe, io-redirection, stderr

I have redircted my ouput using **/dev/null** in bash script but it is still throwing an error. Code is following

```
ps -p $proc | fgrep $proc> /dev/null
if [ $? -ne '0' ] ; then
......
fi
```

below is error

```
error: list of process IDs must follow -p

Usage:
 ps [options]

 Try 'ps --help <simple|list|output|threads|misc|all>'
  or 'ps --help <s|l|o|t|m|a>'
 for additional help text.

For more details see ps(1).
Usage: fgrep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...
Try 'fgrep --help' for more information.
```

How can I suppress this error without affecting **$?** output?

Comment: Not really an answer to your question but I think you'd better check if `$proc` is empty before using it.

Comment: @Aashu; What are you trying to do in the first place? - If you `ps` for a `PID` using `-p` the `grep` seems unnecessary. - You can do (for example): `ps -p "$pid" >/dev/null 2>&1  || echo error`, or: `if ps -p "$pid" >/dev/null 2>&1 ; then echo okay ; else echo error ; fi`.

Comment: Are you testing for existence of the PID `$proc`? If so then use `test -n "$proc" && kill -0 "$proc"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use command grouping:

```
{ ps -p "$proc" | fgrep "$proc";} >/dev/null 2>&1
```

or wrap pipe in subshell:

```
(ps -p "$proc" | fgrep "$proc") >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: You don't need a subshell if all you want is redirecting I/O; you can use command grouping: `{ ps -p "$proc" | fgrep "$proc" ;} >/dev/null 2>&1`.

Comment: I never knew subshells exist. Now I know.

Comment: @Janis: Good point, forgot about it. Updated my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

`&> /dev/null` throws away both `stderr` and `stdout`. Same answer as the others, just a few characters shorter.

Answer (score -1):

redirect error stream to `null` like `ps -p $proc 2> /dev/null | fgrep $proc > /dev/null 2>&1`

Comment: Still getting same error.

Comment: edited the answer @Aashu, try it now